# Combining tail && journalctl

Tags: systemd, tail, journalctl

I'm tailing logs of my own app and postgres.

```
tail -f /tmp/myapp.log /var/log/postgresql/postgresql.main.log
```

I need to include pgpool's logs. It used to be syslog but now it is in journalctl.

Is there a way to tie tail -f && journalctl -f together?

Answer (score 146):

You could use:

```
journalctl -u service-name -f
```

> -f, --follow
>
> Show only the most recent journal entries, and continuously print new entries as they are appended to the journal.

Here I've added "service-name" to distinguish this answer from others; you substitute the actual service name instead of the text `service-name`.

Answer (score 21):

You could [forward your log entries to *journal*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/347573):

```
systemd-cat tail -f /tmp/myapp.log /var/log/postgresql.log
```

and then use `journalctl -f`...  though as Mark mentioned, that will print all journal entries.

---

One way to filter only the messages from those logs and from that particular unit is to use a distinct `SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER` i.e. edit the unit file and under the `[Service]` section add e.g.

```
SyslogIdentifier=my_stuff
```

restart the unit then run `systemd-cat` with the same identifier

```
systemd-cat -t my_stuff tail -f /tmp/myapp.log /var/log/postgresql.log
```

and finally query the journal only for that particular identifier:

```
journalctl -f -t my_stuff
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have bash available, you can use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution) as one of the `tail` parameters:

```
tail -f /tmp/myapp.log /var/log/postgresql/postgresql.main.log <(journalctl -f)
```

Comment: This is the elegant way I also tried, but is doesn't work. Tail shows that it's using /dev/fd/xx, but no logs are displayed.

Comment: correct; /dev/fd/xxx is the temporary pipe that bash uses in order to implement the process substitution; any journalctl output will show up in there.

Comment: You probably don't want to follow the whole journal but just those for the pgpool unit. Assuming the service named `pgpool.service`, try `journalctl -fu pgpool.service`. Also, if you are not running this as root, make sure the user is in the `systemd-journal` group!

Answer (score 1):

try something like:

```
tail -f /tmp/myapp.log >> /tmp/tail.log &
journalctl -f >> /tmp/tail.log &
tail -f /tmp/tail.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [journaltail](https://github.com/gjedeer/journaltail/blob/main/journaltail):

```
journaltail --unit pgpool.service /tmp/myapp.log /var/log/postgresql/postgresql.main.log
```

I just threw the script together an hour ago after looking for a solution at stackoverflow et al.