# Forward logs from file to journald

Tags: systemd, logs, systemd-journald

I have an application that writes logs to some file e.g.  `/var/log/mylog.txt`

However, I want it to be written to `journald` (so that it can be accessed via `journalctl`). I can't change way of launching of application, as it is encapsulated from me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`systemd-cat`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-cat.html), e.g.

```
 systemd-cat cat /path/to/log
```

or

```
 systemd-cat -t encapsulated_app_log tail -f /path/to/log
```

Comment: I tried the second option but it doesn't seem to work. Did you check it? I'm just wondering in case I've done something wrong

Comment: @RahulKatrakhtalapali - works fine here... Note that if you're doing it as a user you will have to run `journalctl` as that specific user to get the expected output